# LibGDX Tiled Map мерцание

Tags: libgdx, map, render

Делаю небольшую игру на LibGDX box2d.

Нарисовал карту в Tiled Map Editor'e, загрузил ее:

```
mMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/testmap2.tmx");
mTmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(mMap, 1/PPI);
```

Отрендерил:

```
camera.update();
mTmr.setView(camera);
mTmr.render();
```

Однако при движении камеры появляются мерцания(полосы заднего фона) между стыками тайлов.
Везде написано, что надо сделать `padding` в тайлсете, но я не совсем понимаю, как... Тем более, если тайлсет я не рисовал, а взял готовый (из игры teeworlds)

Можно ли как-то программно убрать этот баг?
Если нет, то как грамотно создать карту (интересует все: от создания тайлсета до загрузки карты в libgdx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 способа решить данную проблему.

1. Добавить отступ `padding` к тайлам
2. Если вы, как я, взяли готовый тайлсет без отступа, то можно программно решить данную проблему.

При обновлении камеры (перед вызовом `camera.update()`):

```
camera.x = Math.round(camera.x/S)*S;
camera.y = Math.round(camera.y/S)*S;
```

`S` у меня равен `0.005f`